# Related between Kuratowski theorem and any graphs that $\chi(G)\leq 4$ and $\chi(G)\leq 5$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, planar-graphs

Is there related between Kuratowski's theorem and any graphs that $\chi(G)\leq 4$ and $\chi(G)\leq 5$ (chromatic number)?